# perforce excluding part of subfolder

Tags: perforce

I'm trying to exclude all subfolders except for one. I've seen wild cards to include and exclude, is there a way to "exclude all except" ?

An example might make it easier to see what I'm trying to do.
Let's say I have a workspec like so:

//depot/Root/... //PC/Root/...

Under root there are some platform specific files. If I am working on platform D I don't care about platforms A,B,C. Currently I have to do something like this:

-//depot/Root/Binaries/A/... //PC/Root/Binaries/A/...

-//depot/Root/Binaries/B/... //PC/Root/Binaries/B/...

-//depot/Root/Binaries/C/... //PC/Root/Binaries/C/...

Imagine that there are a few subfolders I care about, and many that I don't want. Is there a way to specify something like, exclude this entire folder except for these subfolders?

I tried playing with the order of the workspace mapping but that didn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you want to exclude all the direct subdirectories of `Binaries` other than `D`, but keep everything else under `Root`. How about something like this?

```
//depot/Root/... //PC/Root/...
-//depot/Root/Binaries/... //PC/Root/Binaries/...
//depot/Root/Binaries/D/... //PC/Root/Binaries/D/...
```